# Django Custom Admin Form bulk save implmentation

Tags: python, django, csv

I am trying to implement a CSV Import in Django Admin and save bulk data corresponding to the CSV file's rows.

This is my Admin class:

```
class EmployeeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('user', 'company', 'department', 'designation', 'is_hod', 'is_director')
    search_fields = ['user__email', 'user__first_name', 'user__last_name']
    form = EmployeeForm
```

This is my Form class:

```
class EmployeeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    company = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Companies.objects.all())
    file_to_import = forms.FileField()

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ("company", "file_to_import")

    def save(self, commit=True, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            company = self.cleaned_data['company']
            records = csv.reader(self.cleaned_data['file_to_import'])
            for line in records:
                # Get CSV Data.

                # Create new employee.
                employee = CreateEmployee(...)

        except Exception as e:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Something went wrong.')
```

My Employee class is:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Companies)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Departments)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=16, default="0", blank=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, default="m", choices=GENDERS)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=getImageUploadPath, null=True, blank=True)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    is_hod = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_director = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

When I upload my file and click `save`, it shows me this error:

`'NoneType' object has no attribute 'save'`

with exception location at:

`/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py in save_model, line 1045`

**EDIT** I understand I need to put a call to `super.save`, but I am unable to figure out where to put the call, because the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) says that the save method saves and returns the instance. But in my case, there is no single instance that the superclass can save and return. Wham am I missing here?

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just add the `super().save()` to the the end of the function:

```
def save(self, *args, commit=True, **kwargs):
    try:
        company = self.cleaned_data['company']
        records = csv.reader(self.cleaned_data['file_to_import'])
        for line in records:
            # Get CSV Data.

            # Create new employee.
            employee = CreateEmployee(...)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    except Exception as e:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Something went wrong.')
```

Comment: Ok. So I added the following after my for loop:

`super(EmployeeForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)`

Now it is giving me the following exception:

`(1048, "Column 'user_id' cannot be null")`

Comment: @R4chi7 That may be a problem with how you are creating/using the `User` model.

Comment: The method `CreateEmployee` works fine when I run it via the Django shell. I tried to analyze the queries that are being run in both cases. The queries when saving via admin are: http://pastebin.com/a8qNPd03. The queries when saving via shell are: http://pastebin.com/ipT99d5m. Some extra queries are running in the case of admin.

Comment: I am assuming the extra query with NULL values is happening due to the the `super().save()` call. Am I assuming wrong?

Comment: I should probably put this as a separate question.